# Running TestStack.White automation test in command line

Tags: visual-studio-2012, automated-tests, ui-automation, gui-testing, white-framework

I am using white automation framework to automate my test applications.I attach white visual studio plugin and running the test inside visual studio. For some specific reasons I need to run the automation test cases outside visual studio i.e in command line.Is there any command line options to do so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an expert here, but you can try nunit-console after downloading [this](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download).

Comment: Thanks, I tried white with MSTest, it was failed because my test runner application call test cases in synchronize manner, when I change to an asynchronize call it works fine. I have already tried with NUnit GUI runner, it works there also.